# BigQuery INSERT Error "Syntax error: Expected ")" or "," but got identifier"

Tags: syntax, google-bigquery

I receive an error when using the bq utility, although the same query works in the UI

I've tried modifying my code, but to no avail

x@cloudshell:~ (mynewtestproject-249124)$ bq query --use_legacy_sql=false \

> 'CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE testMe.Categories (
>   CategoryID INT64 NOT NULL ,
>   CategoryName STRING NOT NULL,
>   Description STRING,
>   Picture STRING)'
>   Waiting on bqjob_r6542578b2712ca1a_0000016cd17464d2_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE
>   Replaced mynewtestproject-249124.testMe.Categories

x@cloudshell:~ (mynewtestproject-249124)$ bq query --use_legacy_sql=false \

> 'INSERT
>   testMe.Categories(CategoryID,
>   CategoryName,
>   Description,
>   Picture)
>   VALUES
>   (1,'Beverages','Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales','no picture'),
>   (2,'Condiments','Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings','no picture'),
>   (3,'Confections','Desserts, candies, and sweet breads','no picture'),
>   (4,'Dairy Products','Cheeses','no picture'),
>   (5,'Grains/Cereals','Breads, crackers, pasta, and cereal','no picture'),
>   (6,'Meat/Poultry','Prepared meats','no picture'),
>   (7,'Produce','Dried fruit and bean curd','no picture'),
>   (8,'Seafood','Seaweed and fish','no picture')'
>   Error in query string: Error processing job 'mynewtestproject-249124:bqjob_r604cdbcdd5a22c35_0000016cd174adb4_1': Syntax error: Expected ")" or "," but got
>   identifier "drinks" at [7:19]
>   x@cloudshell:~ (mynewtestproject-249124)$

I tried the same query in the web UI and it worked, but when using the command-line tool (bq), it failed during an INSERT.

Comment: Can you copy paste here the exact code/CLI command running the query?

Comment: It seems you might be quoting the query in the CLI with single quotes and also using single quotes within the query?  Can you try switching outer quotes to `"` and inner quotes to `'` or vice versa?  Your first command seems to run its query correctly, maybe because it doesn't have any inner quotes.